# azure workbook - dropdown parameter values depending on other parameter

Tags: azure, kql, azure-monitor, azure-monitor-workbooks

I want to have two parameters in my workbook: `type` and `subtype`.

`type` parameter value can be either "A" or "B" (Done using a static json `["A", "B"]`).

Values proposed in the dropdown for the `subtype` parameter should be:

- A1", "A2" when selected `type` is "A"
- "B1", "B2", "B3" when selected `type` is "B"

How to achieve that?

I have tried to play with the different query options available but to no avail.

Comment: Provide input and output, how it looks(provide input json and expected output in that example)

Comment: @RithwikBojja my main problem is that I don't know if the input should be a json, and if yes then how and with which format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have one parameter depend on another, you reference that parameter in the query text (or other settings) of the second parameter.

here you can see i have a text parameter `a`, with a value of 'test'.
then, in the parameter `b` i reference that parameter like `{a}` in the query text.  whenever `a` changes, the query in `b` will rerun.

[image: parameter referencing another parameter]

if you are using a json datasource, things get more tricky.  you can really only use the parameters in the result settings tab in things like JSONPath expressions, but it is possible:

[image: starting json data]

#### result settings:

note the reference to the parameter in the jsonpath table expression (this determines the table *rows* in the results)

and also note that it explicitly returns only the id column (if you have a label, also add that.  otherwise it will assume the "filter" column is the "label" column of the dropdown and you'll have N items with the same label.

[image: result settings using json path]

results:
[image: results with filtering]